# Automobiles data catalog

Tags: data-request, cars

I'm looking for API to integrate that provides list of spare parts details, cars details and possibly vin numbers. I have found Tecalliance but they seem to be overpriced for their subscription especially for a startup like mine.

Do you have any suggestions on other data providers? either free or not.
thanks.